# How to install MySQL server on Debian 9

Tags: mysql, debian, installation, mariadb

I try to install mysql server with command `apt-get install mysql-server mysql-common`

But output is:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
mysql-common is already the newest version (5.8+1.0.2).
The following additional packages will be installed:
  default-mysql-server mariadb-client-10.1 mariadb-client-core-10.1
  mariadb-common mariadb-server-10.1 mariadb-server-core-10.1
Suggested packages:
  mariadb-test netcat-openbsd tinyca
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  default-mysql-server mariadb-client-10.1 mariadb-client-core-10.1
  mariadb-common mariadb-server-10.1 mariadb-server-core-10.1 mysql-server
0 upgraded, 7 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 18.8 MB/18.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 169 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

As you can see it will **not install mysql** server but **mariadb-server-10.1** why?

I want mysql not mariadb.

Sources list:

```
deb http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free

# Security
deb http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free

# Backports
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ stretch-backports main contrib non-free
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MariaDB is MySQL. Quote from the [Wikipedia page of MariaDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MariaDB):

> MariaDB is a community-developed fork of the MySQL relational database management system intended to remain free under the GNU GPL. Development is led by some of the original developers of MySQL, who forked it due to concerns over its acquisition by Oracle Corporation.

MariaDB is reported to have better performance than MySQL, and the license conditions are less restrictive. For that reason all major Linux distributions are nowadays shipping MariaDB instead of MySQL. It is fully compatible, every MySQL client can connect to MaraDB and won't notice any difference, so there is no reason to prefer MySQL over MariaDB.

Comment: I also find MariaDB to be more compatible with previous versions of MySQL than the current MySQL version is, which complains over some queries with left joins, so you need to use ANY_VALUE() on some columns whle those columns are unique, so there should not be a problem. I've switched to MariaDB without any problems.

Comment: The "official" packages are avalable from mysql directly. They have a repo https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/